# create a loop containing variables on different lines

Tags: php

My barcode scanner makes a file like this:
03/01/2000-12:59:49-07-21-1229749
03/01/2000-12:59:51-07-0 1 1 0
03/01/2000-12:59:55-07-22-1229749
03/01/2000-12:59:57-07-0 1 1 1

Line 1 containce the id I need 21
Line 2 is the location I need 0 1 1 0
Line 3 again the id 22
Line 4 again the location 0 1 1 1

The file could contain 100 lines

After reading I update the database like:
mysql_query("UPDATE parts SET locatie = '$locatie_regel_2' WHERE id = '$id_regel_1'");

So far I have my script

```
$file = file_get_contents('C:\test\BARCODE.TXT');
$strip = explode("\n", $file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$regel_1_a = $strip[0];
$regel_1_b = explode(':', $regel_1_a);
$regel_1_c = explode('-', $regel_1_b[2]);
$id_regel_1 = $regel_1_c[2];

//echo $id_regel_1;

$regel_2_a = $strip[1];
$regel_2_b = explode(':', $regel_2_a);
$regel_2_c = explode('-', $regel_2_b[2]);
$locatie_regel_2 = $regel_2_c[2];

//echo $locatie_regel_2;
```

I think it could be handled bij a loop or something but I can't get it to work ..
Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` will get you an array of your text file from there you can read that array paired with the data you need:

```
<?php
// load your database information here otherwise the mysql_query will not work.

$data = file('C:\test\BARCODE.TXT', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$total = count($data) - 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; ++$i)
{
    $parts = explode('-', $data[$i]);
    $id = $parts[count($parts) - 2];

    $i++;
    $parts = explode('-', $data[$i]);
    $location = array_pop($parts);

    mysql_query("UPDATE parts SET locatie = '$location' WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

This `for` assumes your data starts with the `id` line and the next line is always the `location`, it will read the data in steps of 2.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help:

```
$a = array();
$file = file_get_contents('C:\test\BARCODE.TXT');
foreach ( $file as $content ) {
    $a[] = array_filter(array_map("trim", explode("\n", $content)));
}

for($i=0;$i<$a.count();$i++){
$a[i][0] = $strip[0];
$a[i][1] = explode(':', $a[i][0]);
$a[i][2] = explode('-', $a[i][1][2]);
$a[i][3] = $a[i][2][2];

    if(i%2!=0)
       mysql_query("UPDATE parts SET locatie = '$a[i][3]' WHERE id = '$a[i-1][3]'");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); parameters should be part of the file() function, not explode.

`$strip = file('C:\test\BARCODE.TXT',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`

This should create the array you are looking for with $strip.

for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($strip);$i+=2) {
   //process strip[i]

// process strip[i+1]
}